# Array slice notation for priming test_train_split?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, slice

I'm working through a tutorial on machine learning, based on the Iris data set:

```
    sepal-length  sepal-width  petal-length  petal-width        class
0            5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
1            4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  Iris-setosa
2            4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  Iris-setosa
...(146 more rows)
```

The dataset ends up being carved up into two separate arrays, X and Y, and fed into `test_train_split`:

```
array = dataset.values
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y,
    test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
```

I'm trying to understand the array slice notation:

```
X = array[:,0:4]
Y = array[:,4]
```

What exactly are these slice commands producing?

Comment: `numpy` [indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), since there exist many more indexing notations you'll probably run into eventually.

Comment: Good find thank @DanielF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = array[:,0:4]
```

X is a 2D array containing all rows in `array`, and columns 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, and 4<sup>th</sup> columns (`[0:4]` - `sepal-length`, `sepal-width`, `petal-length`, and `petal-width`). Its shape will be `(len(array), 4)`

---

```
Y = array[:, 4]
```

Y is a 2D array containing all rows in `array`, and the 5<sup>th</sup> column (`class`) only. Its shape will be (len(array), 1)

---

`X` is extracting the numerical data as training data (columns 0-3), while `Y` is just extracting the corresponding labels (column 4).